# How do I create a mapping table in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, entity-relationship

I'm learning about table design in SQL and I'm wonder how to create a mapping table in order to establish a many-to-many relationship between two other tables?

I think the mapping table needs two primary keys - but I can't see how to create that as it appears there can only be 1 primary key column?

I'm using the Database Diagrams feature to create my tables and relationships.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply select both fields by selecting the first field, and then while holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key selecting the second field. Then clicking the key icon to set them both as the primary key.